# Convert Clojure #inst instant in time to Joda time with clj-time

Tags: parsing, clojure, jodatime, clj-time

What is the right way to parse Clojure time instants like `#inst "2017-01-01T12:00:00"` to Joda time using the [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object:

```
(type #inst "2017-01-01T12:00:00+02:00")
;;=> java.util.Date
```

`clj-time` has a [`clj-time.coerce`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/tree/v0.13.0#clj-timecoerce) namespace with a `from-date` function that takes `java.util.Date` objects as input. Example:

```
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as c])

((juxt type str) (c/from-date #inst "2017-01-01T12:00:00"))
;;=> [org.joda.time.DateTime "2017-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also clj-time now provides a data-reader to automatically coerce dates in EDN to/from joda datetimes: [clj-time EDN support](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time#clj-timecoerce)

```
(clojure.edn/read-string {:readers clj-time.coerce/data-readers}
                         "#clj-time/date-time \"2019-07-10T06:00:00.000Z\"")
==>
#clj-time/date-time "2019-07-10T06:00:00.000Z"
```